# Solving homogeneous linear recurrence relation with double non-constant coefficients

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

I have the following recurrence relation -an eigenvalue problem-

\begin{equation}
(N+1-r) \, a_{r-1} + \frac{(m(r+1))!}{(m r)!} a_{r+1}=C_1 a_{r} \quad r\geq 1,
\end{equation}
with boundary conditions $a_{-1}=a_{N+1}=0$. $m$ is a positive integer $\geq 1$ and $C_1$ a constant. I know that the eigenvectors $a_r$ should be orthogonal polynomials for any $m$. For $m=1$ I get
\begin{equation}
(N+1-r) \, a_{r-1} + (r+1) a_{r+1}=C_1 a_{r}.
\end{equation}
This equation can be solved using a generating function $f(z)=\sum_{r=0}^{N} a_{r} z^{r}$. The differential equation is
\begin{equation}
(1-z^2)f'(z)=(C_1-Nz)f(z).
\end{equation}
The solution of this differential equation is $f(z)=C_2 (1+z)^{\frac{N+C_1}{2}}(1-z)^{\frac{N-C_1}{2}}$ and the eigenvectors $a_{r}$ can be written in terms of orthogonal polynomials using the Rogrigues formula for Jacobi polynomials and $f(z)$. $C_2$ is a constant to be determined by a normalization condition on the eigenvectors $a_r$, and $C_1$ are eigenvalues obtained imposing analiticity in $f(z)$.

For $m=2, 3, \dots$, it gets more complicated
\begin{equation}
(N+1-r) \, a_{r-1} + (2r+2)(2r+1) a_{r+1}=C_1 a_{r},\\
(N+1-r) \, a_{r-1} + (3r+3)(3r+2)(3r+1) a_{r+1}=C_1 a_{r},
\end{equation}
and so on.

Could anybody give me a hint on how to get (if possible) the generating function $f(z)$ for $m\geq2$?

Comment: Using wolfram
$$(m*(n+1))!/(m*n)!*a(n+1) = c*a(n)  $$
gives
$$a(n) = \frac{c_1 c^{(n - 1)} Γ(m + 1)}{Γ(m n + 1)}$$ 

(where $c_1$ is an arbitrary parameter)
$$.$$
Adding the term $-(N+1-n)*a(n-1)$ to the right runs out of time.

$$(m*(n+1))!/(m*n)!*a(n+1) = c*a(n) -(N+1-n)*a(n-1) $$